# Compilation error in maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-7

I got the following error when I build my project with maven. I am using jdk 1.7.0_03 but it tells me like follows.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project sample: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] /home/dinithi/Training/Practise/Carbon_Assignment/LibrarySystem/Components/src/main/java/com/wso2/carbon/library/sample/LibraryManager.java:[11,7] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

I am using a HashMap in my code as follows.

```
Map<String,Book> books=new HashMap<String,Book>();
```

Can someone help me with this error.

P.S. I am using intellij idea as my IDE.

Comment: Read your error message, especially the last sentence.

Comment: you need to change `-source 1.3` to atleast `-source 1.5`

Comment: I believe it is really obvious: you have set the source compatibility to 1.3 instead of >=1.5.  Check in POM what is the `source` setting in `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration

Comment: What isn't so obvious is that in this case no source level is set all; 1.3 is just the default that will be used if you don't specify anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add (or change) the source element to plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: As JDK 1.7 is used, version better be 1.7.

Comment: Thanks alot. I forgot to add this plugin. :)